# How do you feed reviews to Google places page for businesses?

Tags: seo, google-search, local-seo, google-local-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to provide Google reviews information?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5550/how-to-provide-google-reviews-information)

Check out this google places page as an example:

http://maps.google.com/maps/place?hl=en&sugexp=erf1&pq=virginia+honda+&cp=17&gs_id=50&xhr=t&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&ix=sea&biw=1600&bih=1109&um=1&ie=UTF-8&q=los+angeles+honda+dealers&fb=1&gl=ca&hq=honda+dealers&hnear=0x80c2c75ddc27da13:0xe22fdf6f254608f4,Los+Angeles,+CA,+USA&cid=17542835494479136794&ei=rnuxT_xqw4SDB4ynhakJ&sa=X&oi=local_result&ct=placepage-link&resnum=3&sqi=2&ved=0CL0BEOIJMAI

At the bottom you will see

Reviews from around the web: citysearch.com (49) - insiderpages.com (18) - dealerrater.com (37)

I'm working on a website that is a similar to these directories, people can come and review dealers.

We've marked the reviews with rich snippets, the problem is sometimes they do show up on some google places pages and sometimes they do not.

It seems completely random, google links to wrong pages, and also the count is not accurate.

I was wondering if there is an official guide on how to do this properly or if this is less about technical aspects of doing this and more about business relationships with directories and google.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Google seems to pick and choose where to get the reviews for Google Places from externally. You can try to ask Google about having reviews from your website posted but I am sure they will say no.

Comment: Well the thing is they do show our reviews too, but not for all businesses, and also not properly